# Thread concurrency when commiting changes Entity Framework

Tags: .net, multithreading, entity-framework, concurrency, savechanges

I have three threads consuming a method that Adds an entity in the database with a repository

this is the method that gets used by three consecutive threads:

```cs
       public async Task SaveAssets(string socketName)
        {
            var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var securityListRepository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISecurityListRepository>();
            var uow = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUnitOfWork>();

            List<AssetModel> assetsList = _socketsAssets[socketName]?.Where(asset => asset != null).ToList();

            foreach (var asset in assetsList)
            {
                asset.ServerReference = socketName;
                securityListRepository.Add(asset);
            }

            if (await uow.Commit())
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Commited");
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError("Not Commited");
            }
        }
```

I read in the EF Documentation saying that: if i has a problem with concurrency access to DbContext, than use `ServiceScopeFactory` to create a new scope of the Repository (the class inherits another class with DbContext) to each thread, so i did it;

This works when a thread try to Add a bunch (10k+) of entities to the repository;

But it seems like when a thread starts to commit the changes, and another thread starts to commit too, it will throw `sqlite Error 5: 'database is locked'. entity framework`

OBS: Im using SQLite database

This is caused because one thread starting commiting the changes, and another one comes and starts to commit concurrently?

The database locked is happening because im using SQLite or is it normal to lock when i do multiple commits?

OBS: The Repository, UnityOfWork and the DbContext lifetime is Scoped.

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
services.AddScoped<ISecurityListRepository, SecurityListRepository>();
```

Comment: I was under the impression that DbContext is not thread safe and should never be updated by multiple threads